# Prevent search index of list column

Tags: 2013, search, cross-site-publishing

We are using cross-site publishing with a library in Site A and surfacing the content in Site B. Here is [documentation about cross-site-publishing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/overview-of-cross-site-publishing). About 2/3 down the page is a section about **Content metadata in the search index**.

> ...To include crawled properties in the search index, crawled properties are mapped to managed properties. This is because only managed properties are included in search results. ...

I took that to mean that only managed properties are included in the cross-site published catalog search.

We have a list field called *Catalog notes* which the admins use to keep some notes about the entries they are working on. Words that appear only in the notes are providing hits on Site B -- they appear as results and hit highlighting.

We don't want this "admin only" column from Site A to be included in Search results in Site B.

Since it is list field it has a crawled property and no managed property, so it shouldn't be included in the search results according to the above quote. I checked in the Site Collection > Search Schema to make sure that a managed property wasn't generated and there isn't.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/exclude-column-from-sharepoint-search-crawl.html) which shows how to exclude a column from SharePoint Search Crawl. Site Settings > Searchable columns. I tried that but the **Catalog notes** column doesn't show up there because it is not a site column -- meaning it shouldn't be indexed to begin with!

There is a crawled property *ows_CatalogNotes*. When I edit the crawled property I see it isn't mapped to anything. But I think the issue might be that the "Include in full-text index" is checked. It is also not available for me to change.

Any ideas how to prevent this library list column in Site A from being indexed and included in search results in Site B? (Or from search results anywhere if that is easier!)

**Edit**

I found [What makes a SharePoint column searchable?](https://www.techmikael.com/2014/07/what-makes-sharepoint-column-searchable.html) which shows that if there is a crawled property with full text index, but a mangaged property that is not searchable, that the column will not be searchable. I've tried mapping **Catalog Notes** to a managed property called **NoSearch** and we'll see if that works. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in site settings.  In your case it would be Site A.

```
http(s)://<Site A URL>/_layouts/15/NoCrawlSettings.aspx
```

And then select "Exclude" for the column that you want to not be indexed.

Comment: Thanks BigRaj that is the page that the tutorial showed me. Because my column is not a Site Column it doesn't appear on that page.

Comment: Is recreating the column as a site column and attaching it to the list content type a viable option?  Data can be copied into the new column via code or workflow.

Comment: Trying to avoid replacing the column, hundreds of items will need to go through an approval process. But might be the only way.

Comment: I haven’t been able to find a way to convert a list column to a site column.  It may be the only way from a business process standpoint.

Comment: @BigRaj what if there are 100+ sites in site collection and we need to exclude pages Author field everywhere?